# Why can "populace" be used as an adjective in "most populace cities?"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I wanted to talk about the cities where the population is high. My correspondent told me we must say:

> The most **populace** cities

Instead of:

> The most **populated** cities

I don't understand how the noun *populace* can be used as an adjective. Can you explain that to me?

Answer (score 72):

You've misheard, but it's an easy mistake to make. What the person suggested was:

> The most **populous** cities

*Populace* and *populous* are homophones—Oxford Dictionaries lists both as /'pɒpjʊləs/. Here are the definitions of the two words (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**populace**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/populace)
>   NOUN
>
> *[treated as singular or plural]* The people living in a particular country
>   or area.
>   *"the party misjudged the mood of the populace"*
>
> ---
>
> [**populous**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/populous)
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Having a large population; densely populated.
>   *"the populous city of Shanghai"*

As for why *populous* must be used instead of *populated*, it depends on the meaning you're trying to put across. If you wanted it to mean "cities with the most people," you'd be fine (in my opinion) using *populated*. If you wanted it to mean "cities with the highest population density," I think you'd have to use *populous* instead.

Comment: _Populated_ just means "having people", at all.   [Calico, California,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calico,_San_Bernardino_County,_California) is not populated.  If you wanted to say  "cities with the most people," you'd need "most _heavily_ populated" (and even that suggests density rather than absolute numbers).

Comment: This is also an extremely common mistake made by native writers.

Comment: Yeah ... it's possible that the OP didn't mishear, but the correspondent made a spelling mistake.

Comment: @chrylis: Is it? Never seen it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think s/he might have meant the original "mistake" the correspondent corrected, that of *populated* vs. *populous*. I'd agree that you hear people say "populated" at this juncture almost every time. Partly because the word "populous" is effectively isolated to journalism. ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak: I see people writing "populous" when they meant "populace" All. The. [insert expletive here]. Time. The reverse mistake is much rarer.

Comment: @Martha Well, I certainly agree that "populace" is even *less* in everyday use than "populous"!

Comment: For what it's worth, @Malvolio is right and LMS's current answer is simply wrong for that part of the question. Given that it's already sitting on a pile of upvotes and is going to be the accepted answer, what's the best solution? To just edit it to correct the original writer's misunderstanding?

Comment: @Martha: Never seen it. Maybe it's an American thing. In actual English I've never encountered it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've seen it in both, however more often in British English.

Comment: @That1Guy: You must live out in farm country ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it's an SCA thing: people often want to talk about the kingdom's populace, but end up talking about the nonsensical concept of the kingdom's populous instead.

Comment: @Martha: Sorry what's SCA?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Society for Creative Anachronism. Medieval LARP.

Comment: @lly: For what it's worth, there was a (now-deleted) comment thread discussing *populated* vs. *populous* that agreed that *populated* was acceptable. I originally didn't include the last paragraph in my answer, but that comment thread asked that I do. It's my opinion that "most populated," while perhaps not strictly correct, is so widely used and widely understood that it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @chrylis maybe your LARPers grew up playing [Populous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populous_(series))